# Spring 3.0 REST implementation or Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring, jax-rs

I'm currently trying to figure out which implementation of JSR-311 I'm going to recommend further up the food chain. I've pretty much narrowed it down to two options - Spring 3.0 with it's native support for REST - or use Sun's own Jersey (Restlets *might* also be an option).

To me it doesn't seem to be much of a difference in the actual syntax, but there might be issues with performance that I haven't figured out yet.

The service is meant to replace some heavy-duty EJB's and make a RESTful Webservice instead. The load is expected to be rather high, up in the 100k users per day (max) range, but will be seriously load balanced.

Thanks for all your insights.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring 3 is not an implementation of JSR-311.  Maybe that's enough to answer it for you?  If you want JAX-RS on Spring, you'd be using (most likely) Jersey as the provider anyway!  I would think if you're already an EJB shop, having everyone learn the Spring MVC way of doing it may not be too useful, if EJB3 is the next step for you?

Here's an article!
http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the answer - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 13):

You might be interested in [this InfoQ comparison](http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs) of Spring 3.0 MVC and JAX-RS.

It is a bit biased since it is written by "a senior consultant at SpringSource", but I think it's a fair and in-depth comparison of both technologies.